# Namespace problems between custom/user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, namespaces, custom-controls

I have a project I've been working on for quite a while, and I've run into a referencing problem.  Currently the solution outline looks like this:

**Solution**

1. Agent_Toolbox namespace

   - MainWindow
   - CallTemplate (UserControl)

     - CallTemplate class
2. CustomTextBoxes namespace

   - NumberTextBox (CustomControl)

     - NumberTextBox class

My problem is that `CallTemplate` uses one of the `NumberTextBox` custom controls.  I need to reference the `CallTemplate` class from within the NumberTextBox class in a `typeof` statement. ie:

```cs
ParentControls parentControl = new ParentControls();
Visual parent = parentControl.GetParentControls(this, 3);
if (parent == typeof(CallTemplate))
{
    //Do something
}
```

But no matter what I try I can't get VS to recognize CallTemplate in this instance as a class.  I tried adding a reference to NumberTextBox, but it gives me an error of circular redundancy.  I also tried seperating `CallTemplate` into a separate namespace, but then *it* can't find `NumberTextBox` without a circular redundancy.  Ont thing I thought of doing was placing all the User/Custom controls into a separate project within the solution, but then the xaml couldn't find CustomTextBoxes in order to add the box into the CallTemplate.  I'm prertty much frustrated and at a loss, and convinced it's something simple I'm missing.

Any ideas please?

**Edit:**

I added a UserControl to the CustomTextBoxes project.  VS studio placed it within the same namespace, and generated

```
public partial class CallTemplate: UserContol
{
    public CallTemplate()
    {
         InitializaComponent();
    }
}
```

If I try to rename the namespace it renames the whole namespace, rather than just this file's.  So I created a new namespace underneath, and pasted the `CallTemplate` code within it.  VS balked at the `InitializeComponent()` method, saying it doesn't exist with in the current context.  Basically I need to know how to migrate one part of a namespace's code to a different namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two projects cannot reference each other. If they did, how would visual studio know which to build first? When that happens, it usually means it's a design flaw. Combine your projects, or have the references only go one way.

Comment: Do you mean combine as in place both individually into one project, or make it all one custom control library?

Comment: If they have to reference each other, then they need to be in the same project. Separation by namespace, within one project, would be a great way to organize it.

Comment: So in trying to do just that, the `InitializeComponent()` method says it does not exist in the current context.  How can I update that?

Comment: What doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: The response was long and involved a decent amount of code, so I placed it as an edit above.  Thanks btw for being so helpful so far with this. :)

Comment: @KevenM Is it possible to delete and recreate the control? Sometimes that's easiest when VS is trying to create some code for you.